# Objective-C: Evenly displaying NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

If I am looping through a bunch of strings and want to say use them as the stringValue of a NSTextField or title of a NSButton programmatically is there a way to determine the length I will need for the frame of the textfield or buttons and the spacing between...I know this is kind of relevant to the font selected for each but it would be great if I could dynamically figure out NSString.length = x pixels. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

Look into the sizeWithFont method on NSString.

```
CGSize size = [mystring sizeWithFont:myfont];
```

CGSize has a height and width that you can then examine.